# Probability That Hat And Shirt Will Be Different Colors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Do not have answer to this problem

Please let me know if there are mistakes


John has 3 hats, 5 shirts, 3 pairs of pants and 6 pairs of socks.

More specifically he has:

- A red, blue and black hat
- 2 red shirts and 3 blue shirts
- 2 blue pants and one pair of black pants
- 2 red socks, 2 blue socks and 2 black socks

If he dresses himself at random, what is the probability that his hat and shirt will be different colors?

Attempt:

[image: Set of unique hat and shirt]

> This part I'm not sure if right 
>  
>  Ways to wear Unique Hat &
> Shirt Color 
>  
> = $4$ Unique Hat & Shirt sets * 3 Pants * 6 Socks 
> = 72

Total ways to wear random clothes


= 3 Hats * 5 Shirts * 3 Pants * 6 Socks

= 270

Probability John will dress random and have unique Hat and Shirt color:


${72\over 270} = 0.2666 $

Comment: Not every of the four combinations is equally probable, as there are more blue shirts than red shirts. Your combinatorial approach works too if you take these multiplicities into account.

Comment: Attempted with multiplicities taken into account, got same answer as paw88789 method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that matters are hats and shirts.

P(red hat, blue shirt) $= \frac13\cdot\frac35=\frac{1}{5}$

Do this for the other combinations where hats and shirts are different colors.  Then add the resulting probabilities.